# How can I determine the name of the website by scraping the webpage?

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

Suppose some webpage is opened in my browser and I scraped the source code using scrapy. How can I identify the name of the website? I mean it can be in any tag. How can I uniquely identify it?

Comment: Your question isn't clear, try to improve it :)

Comment: You can identify it with `response.url`, with parsed domain via urlparse, with page title, with anything. Can you explain, what do you mean?

Comment: Define "name of the website". Domain ? page `<title>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for the tag  in the .

For example, one can use something like: `response.xpath('//title')`

Comment: what if i want to extract the url of the webpage??

Comment: You're welcome, from an object response you can do: `response.request.url` to obtain the URL. Hope it helps.